# Finding a function to a given Contour line with stipulated conditions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Give to every of these points an example and show, that your example complies the stipulated conditions.

(i) A function $j$ whose contour line to the value $2$ is a circle with radius $17$ around the centre $(1,0)$

(ii) A function $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, whose contour line to the value $1$ is a straight line, which goes through $(1,0)$ and $(2,5)$

My idea:

(i) $j: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto x^2+(y-1)^2-287$

(Since $x^2+(y-1)^2=17^2$ is a circle with radius $17$ and centre $(0,1)$ and it has to be $f(x,y)=c$)

(ii) $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto 5x-y-4$

Is my solution correct? Is there any better way, to do this?